# Applying calculation per groups within R dataframe

Tags: r, aggregation, data.table

I have data like that:

```
object category country
495647 1        RUS  
477462 2        GER  
431567 3        USA  
449136 1        RUS  
367260 1        USA  
495649 1        RUS  
477461 2        GER  
431562 3        USA  
449133 2        RUS  
367264 2        USA  
...
```

where one object appears in various `(category, country)` pairs and countries share a single list of categories.

I'd like to add another column to that, which would be a category weight per country - the number of objects appearing in a category for a category, normalized to sum up to 1 within a country (summation only over unique `(category, country)` pairs).

I could do something like:

```
aggregate(df$object, list(df$category, df$country), length)
```

and then calculate the weight from there, but what's a more efficient and elegant way of doing that directly on the original data.

Desired example output:

```
object category country weight
495647 1        RUS     .75
477462 2        GER     .5 
431567 3        USA     .5 
449136 1        RUS     .75
367260 1        USA     .25
495649 1        RUS     .75
477461 3        GER     .5
431562 3        USA     .5
449133 2        RUS     .25
367264 2        USA     .25
...
```

The above would sum up to one within country for unique `(category, country)` pairs.

Comment: probably belongs on stackoverflow

Comment: Some expected output data would be nice; e.g., to clarify whether the result for rows 1 and 4 should both be 50% or both be 100%. You ask for the category weight by country, directly on the original data, so that seems to imply the latter? But then it won't sum to 1 within country, iiuc.

Comment: thanks Matthew, you are quite right - it should be 100% ( or 1 ) for rows 1 and 4. the weight should sum up to 1 within a country only accounting for unique (category, country) pairs - i'm editing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Responding specifically with the final sentence in mind: "What's a more efficient and elegant way of doing that directly on the original data.", it just so happens that [`data.table`](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) has a new feature for this.

```
install.packages("data.table", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
# Needs version 1.8.1 from R-Forge.  Soon to be released to CRAN.
```

With your data in `DT` :

```
> DT[, countcat:=.N, by=list(country,category)]     # add 'countcat' column
    category country countcat
 1:        1     RUS        3
 2:        2     GER        1
 3:        3     USA        2
 4:        1     RUS        3
 5:        1     USA        1
 6:        1     RUS        3
 7:        3     GER        1
 8:        3     USA        2
 9:        2     RUS        1
10:        2     USA        1

> DT[, weight:=countcat/.N, by=country]     # add 'weight' column
    category country countcat weight
 1:        1     RUS        3   0.75
 2:        2     GER        1   0.50
 3:        3     USA        2   0.50
 4:        1     RUS        3   0.75
 5:        1     USA        1   0.25
 6:        1     RUS        3   0.75
 7:        3     GER        1   0.50
 8:        3     USA        2   0.50
 9:        2     RUS        1   0.25
10:        2     USA        1   0.25
```

`:=` adds a column by reference to the data and is an 'old' feature. The new feature is that it now works by group.  `.N` is a symbol that holds the number of rows in each group.

These operations are memory efficient and should scale to large data; e.g., `1e8`, `1e9` rows.

If you don't wish to include the intermediate column `countcat`, just remove it afterwards. Again, this is an efficient operation which works instantly regardless of the size of the table (by moving pointers internally).

```
> DT[,countcat:=NULL]     # remove 'countcat' column
    category country weight
 1:        1     RUS   0.75
 2:        2     GER   0.50
 3:        3     USA   0.50
 4:        1     RUS   0.75
 5:        1     USA   0.25
 6:        1     RUS   0.75
 7:        3     GER   0.50
 8:        3     USA   0.50
 9:        2     RUS   0.25
10:        2     USA   0.25
>
```

Comment: it is indeed elegant and efficient solution, thank you! One note: I wasn't familiar with `data.table` package and found that 1./ the R-project.org repository requires R > 2.15 and 2./ DT must be a `data.table` - so I had to do `DT = data.table(DT)` on my original data frame.

Comment: As an infrequent user of data.table, I am sometimes confused by the different ways to accomplish things and I often have to look up things. Are there any plans to build a more comprehensive documentation that will replace the FAQ that constitutes the vignette at the moment?

Comment: @ilprincipe I know what you mean and fully agree. There are no plans though because we don't know what it should look like! What would you like? Would a wiki with common use cases be good? Any help you can provide _what_ is needed and _how_ would be really appreciated. If you could sketch out or start the format that you'd like I'll gladly fill it in. A new page on the existing data.table wiki? Somewhere else? Wiki format or something that is reproducible? We need help and guidance on this please. Even a list of the common idioms as you see them would be a great start.

Comment: @nikola Apologies, I should have mentioned that to you. Well done for working it out. Btw, `as.data.table` is usually faster than `data.table` to convert, but we'll change it so you don't need to know that for convenience. Or just start with `data.table` in the first place.

Comment: I guess an extension of the Wiki format would be desirable. As a first step, it could be a unique address that lists _all_ idioms and a more or less complete list of common usage cases. A proper vignette/intro should imho focus more on introducing data.table and its usage by itself, and to a lesser degree on its comparison with data frames and computational speed. I know speed is a selling point, but it should be separated more. Most users figure this out pretty quickly anyways. I feel I am not familiar enough with data.table yet to contribute much, but I will think about this a bit more.

Comment: hey, @MatthewDowle i must revisit this because i failed to install the 1.8.1 on our gentoo production server from the r-project.org repo (i see only mac and windows builds there). When is that expected to go to CRAN, or could I get the 1.8.1 source and compile it myself; or could you possibly elaborate on a 1.8.0 solution? I'd be very thankful on any feedback.

Comment: @nikola failed to install? What did you type? What was the error message? Obviosly there is an error somewhere, but I'm not a mind reader.

Comment: @MatthewDowle sorry, i should've been clearer; I successfully installed it on OS X using `install.packages("data.table", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")` but the same didnt work on a 64 bit gentoo linux machine raising this warning message: _package 'data.table' is not available (for R version 2.15.0)_

Comment: @nikola Ahah, thanks. If you read again the R-Forge page it does state it is only available in binary form for latest R I.e. 2.15.0.  Happily I think it also says you can set method="source" and it should build ok for previous versions of R, or upgrade to R 2.15.0+. It isn't on CRAN yet because I need to iron out the minor bugs on the bug tracker.

Comment: @MatthewDowle thanks, but that's the thing - i am already running 2.15.0 on that machine too.. so it got me wondering - could it be that this http://download.r-forge.r-project.org/bin/ has no linux/unix index .. ?

Comment: anyway, i will try to build it from source and see what happens

Comment: @nikola. Now R 2.15.1 is out maybe it already requires 2.15.1, but I thought it was 2.15*.  Or did you check build and check logs displayed on R-Forge for anything strange?

Comment: @MatthewDowle fyi the latest svn checkout compiled (R CMD INSTALL) under the gentoo linux r 2.15.0, thank you !

Comment: @Nikola  That's great news. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 2):

I actually asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225621/faster-way-to-create-variable-that-aggregates-a-column-by-id) some time ago. data.table is really nice for this, especially now that := by group is implemented, and a self join is not necessary anymore - as illustrated above. the best solution from base R is `ave()`. `tapply()` can also be used.

This is similar to the solution above, using `ave()`. However, I highly recommend you look at data.table.

```
df$count <- ave(x = df$object, df$country, df$category, FUN = length)
df$weight <- ave(x = df$count, df$country, FUN = function(x) x/length(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a readable way to do it in one line. But it can be quite compact.

```
# Use table to get the counts.
counts <- table(df[,2:3])
# Normalize the table
weights <- t(t(counts)/colSums(counts))
# Use 'matrix' selection by names.
df$weight <- weights[as.matrix(df[,2:3])]
```