# Getting the mean value in groups of an id

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [faster way to create variable that aggregates a column by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225621/faster-way-to-create-variable-that-aggregates-a-column-by-id)

So the thing is that i have following data loaded from a CSV file:

```
id      value2  value3
1.000   0.010   14        
1.000   0.019   15        
0.995   0.024   13        
0.995   0.031   20        
0.990   0.012   13        
.....
```

I want to calculate the mean/median etc. value of `value2` and `value3` in groups of `id`. Afterwards the plan was to be able to sort the result by either `value2` or `value3`.

Is there a way to do such task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The duplicate question might not be a perfect match but this is quite basic and has been asked _many_ times here before.  `aggregate`, `tapply`, `split` along with `lapply`/`sapply` and/or `ddply` from the plyr package can all accomplish what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(plyr)
result <- ddply(df, .(id), function(x) { 
    data.frame(mv2 = mean(x$value2), mv3 = mean(x$value3))
    })

# order by mean value2
arrange(result, mv2)
# and for value 3
arrange(result, mv3)
```

Answer (score 6):

It's data.table Sunday! This will scale well for big data -- fast and efficient.

```
> library(data.table)
> DT <- as.data.table(df)
> DT[, list(val2=mean(value2), val3=mean(value3)), by=id]
      id   val2 val3
1: 1.000 0.0145 14.5
2: 0.995 0.0275 16.5
3: 0.990 0.0120 13.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the data in a data frame called `df` you can do the following:

```
sapply(split(df[-1], df$id), sapply, mean)
```